# How can I edit post data before it is saved?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions, customization

I have a plugin and I would like to be able to run the post content through some filters before it is saved to the database. From looking at the [plugin api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), I see that two hooks that look like they might be helpful:

```
save_post
wp_insert_post
```

The only problem is that it looks like `save_post` does not need return a variable, and so I don't know how to filter the content, and `wp_insert_post` looks documented.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
add_action('whatever_hook_name','my_function');

function my_function($post_content){
    return $post_content.' <br> This post was saved on '.time();
}
```

I am going to do something more useful than append a timestamp, namely running some regex filters, but this is the general type of filter / action I'm trying to add.

**Update**

Please note that I want to intercept the data on it's way to being saved in the database - not when it is being displayed in the post (eg: Not by adding a filter to `the_content`)

Comment: Note: You have a bad design :-) 1. everytime post would be saved, this string would be appended. (if you don't delete the previous one, you get a lot's of "`This post was...`"s 2. data such this one should be stored as a meta value of the post :-) BTW: `save_post` is called ***after*** data was saved, therefore ***after*** it was saved to database (not what you want).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [wp_insert_post_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter can do that:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post title
    $data['post_title'] .= '_suffix';
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: got me going in the right direction, thanks. i think you actually need to use `add_action` though instead of `add_filter`. also your `wpse35931_filter_post_data` and `filter_handler` are incongruent...

Comment: It is **definitely** a filter. Though filters and actions are based on the same functionality which allows some crossover. If you use this as an action, however, you will *not* be able to return the data which would remove the whole point. You want to FILTER the data and then return it.

Comment: `wp_insert_post_data` works, but is a bit overpowered for what OP (and perhaps others) want to accomplish.  A simpler option in this situation is `content_save_pre` as recommended by @drzaus.

Comment: Developer docs for `wp_insert_post_data` filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/

Comment: Does this hook get called whenever you 
a) manually call wp_insert_post() in, for example, functions.php of your theme to insert/update a post
OR
b) whenever a post is saved by any means possible (e.g. thru backend, thru frontend, somehow else...)?

Comment: Is it possible to change the second argument $postarr? So the post metadata before saving it?

Answer (score 10):

Use filter `content_save_pre` exactly like `the_content` -- the difference is that it operates when a post is saved, rather than displayed.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre

Answer (score 5):

You can also check for the hook `pre_post_update`

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'before_data_is_saved_function');

function before_data_is_saved_function($post_id) {

}
```

Comment: Does it work for post creation?

Comment: According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/, `pre_post_update` is only called on update, not create.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to the active theme to replace `<shell>` with `[shell]` before saving:

```
 add_filter('content_save_pre', 'my_sanitize_content', 10, 1);
 function my_sanitize_content($value) {
   return str_replace('<shell>', '[shell]', $value);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to add something similar at the end of all the posts, then I would suggest you use the `the_content` filter.

```
function append_to_content( $content ) {
    global $post;
    return $content.'<br />This post was saved on '.$post->post_date;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'append_to_content' );
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually want to edit the data before it is saved in the database.