# get post meta before it is updated (during SAVE_POST)

Tags: save-post

Lets say I have custom field on post editor, and I change value from **AAA** to **ZZZ**.. :

```
add_action('save_post', 
   function($post){
      $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mykey');

   }
, 1);
```

How to get the old value (**AAA**) of that meta-key? during save_post (even earlier 1st priority),  I get **ZZZ**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `save_post` Runs whenever a post or page is created or updated, which
>   could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by
>   email. Action function arguments: post ID and post object. Runs after
>   the data is saved to the database.

above paragraph is quoted from WP Codex.

so you cannot use this hook to get older value because it fires after saving new values to DB. WP has another action hook named `wp_insert_post`but sadly this hook does same thing as `save_post`

alternatively you can use Filters to get the job done. WP provides few filter to edit the post while saving or before saving to DB. like [`wp_insert_post_data`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) & [`content_save_pre`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) might work for you, i think.

**Update**

[here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/how-can-i-edit-post-data-before-it-is-saved) is another discussionon this topic which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

The trick I did was:

1) Created a hidden meta box, where I inserted input, with value of `current_meta_value`
2) during `save_post` i checked it against to `new_meta_value`.

that was all.

Answer (score 1):

This might be against the WordPress-rules or something. But I got this working:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp258055_save_post_callback' );

function wp258055_save_post_callback( $post_id ){
  $value_in_db = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mykey', true );
  $value_about_to_be_saved = $_POST['mykey'];
}
```