# How to filter into post meta data before saving

Tags: filters, post-meta

I'm on a plugin, where I want to provide a way to my clients to filter data before saving. I know the best way is to provide a filter hook. So I introduced a new filter hook to filter all the post data, including post data and post meta data.

But then I found that, there's already a [hook available for post data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/35993/22728). So I realized that, it's unnecessary to introduce another hook to filter post data.

Now I'm wondering is there any such hook available for post meta data? If so, then I won't need to provide any new filter hook, I can direct my users to those filter hooks from the core.

I found [an article by *Igor Benic* about metadata filter hook](https://www.ibenic.com/hook-wordpress-metadata/). I tried with the following code and some of its variances:

```
function wpse22728_meta($check, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique) {
    if( get_post_type($object_id) == 'mycpt' ) {
        if( $meta_key == 'mycustomkey' ) {
            // var_dump($meta_value); //value going to store is: 'old_value'
            return $meta_value = 'new_value';
        }
    }
}

add_filter('add_post_metadata', 'wpse22728_meta', 20, 5);
add_filter('update_post_metadata', 'wpse22728_meta', 20, 5);
```

But actually failed.

How can I filter meta data before storing them? Is there any other hook available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `add_post_metadata` and `update_post_metadata` filters are meant to allow filtering whether a specific meta data should be saved (added/updated) or not, only. The default value (of `$check`) is a `null`, and if you return anything other than *exactly* `null` (i.e. `!== null`), the meta data will not be saved (into the database).

However, the `add_metadata()` function (used by `add_post_meta()`) and the `update_metadata()` function (used by `update_post_meta()`), both use `sanitize_meta()` for sanitizing the meta value (although sanitization are done via filters and *not* the function itself), and the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_meta) says:

> Applies filters that can be hooked to perform specific sanitization
>   procedures for the particular metadata type and key. Does not sanitize
>   anything *on its own*. Custom filters must be hooked in to do the
>   work. The filter hook tag has the form
>   "`sanitize_{$meta_type}_meta_{$meta_key}`".

So in your case, the `$meta_type` would be `post`, and `$meta_key` would be `mycustomkey`, and you could filter the value like so:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_post_meta_mycustomkey', function( $value ){
    return 'new_value';
} );
```

Check also this [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_meta#Example).

### Drawback

Unfortunately, the `sanitize_meta()` doesn't pass the "object" (e.g. post or user) ID to the sanitization filters (i.e. functions hooked to `sanitize_{$meta_type}_meta_{$meta_key}`).

There's a way to overcome that, but it will depend on your code/context, so I can't explain the "how".

### UPDATE

Actually, there's a tricky (or hacky?) solution, which works fine with the `add_post_metadata` and `update_post_metadata` filters. But I'm not including the code here (yet), and you can find it on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pimmXQyJ).

Comment: I think I should provide a custom filter hook for my meta data only. The post data will be filtered with `wp_insert_post_data` and meta data will be filtered using my custom hook. Otherwise it'd be too messy for my clients to do a simple filter. BTW thank you very much for the detailed answer and workaround. It surely has its merit.

Comment: I agreed with what you said about providing a custom filter hook (and I actually wanted to suggest that, but ended up not saying so). And, you're very welcome. =)